Stack over flow when saving the files in a loop the kernel dies i have settled sleep but didn't help that much
import os
import random
import time
import gc
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
import logging
import asyncio
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()  # Allows nested event loops in Jupyter

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()


class DatasetAugmentation:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.Data = data
        self.audio_pitch_range = [-2, 2]  # Pitch shift in semitones
        self.audio_stretch_range = [0.8, 1.2]  # Stretch rate
        self.snr_range = [10, 30]  # SNR for noise addition
        self.reverb_decay_range = [0.2, 0.6]  # Reverb decay
        self.reverb_delay_range = [20, 100]  # Reverb delay in ms
        self.load_sr = 16000
        self.max_voice_length = 30#sec
        self.datasetbalance = 20
        self.augmentation_variations = 4
        self.needed_augs = 0
        self.saving_break = 1
    async def augment_dataset(self):
        """
        Process the dataset sequentially with memory optimization.
        """
        try:
            for speaker in self.Data:
                dir_name = speaker[0][1]
                ultrasounds = len(speaker)
                if ultrasounds < self.datasetbalance:
                    self.needed_augs, aug_rounds = self.calculate_augs_loop(ultrasounds)
                    voices = [voice for voice, name in speaker]
                    aug_list = random.choices(voices, k=aug_rounds)
                    logger.info(f"Processing speaker folder: {dir_name}")
    
                    for file in aug_list:
                        try:
                            logger.info(f"Loading file: {file}")
                            
                            wave, sr = await self.load_audio(file, self.load_sr)
                            #await wave, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=self.load_sr, mono=True, offset=0.0, duration=None)
                            logger.info(f"Starting augmentation for file: {file}")
    
                            # Perform augmentations
                            await self.process_augmentation(wave, sr, file, dir_name)
    
                            # Release memory after processing each file
                            del wave, sr
                            gc.collect()
                            await asyncio.sleep(3)  # Small delay to reduce CPU load
                        except Exception as e:
                            logger.error(f"Error processing file {file}: {e}")

                logger.info(f"Finished processing speaker folder: {dir_name}")
                gc.collect()
                self.needed_augs = 0
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error augmenting dataset: {e}")

    async def load_audio(self, file, sr):
        """
        Asynchronously load audio using librosa.
        """
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        wave, sample_rate = await loop.run_in_executor(
            None, lambda: librosa.load(file, sr=sr, mono=True, offset=0.0, duration=None)
        )
        if wave.shape[0] / sr > self.max_voice_length:
            wave = wave[:sr * self.max_voice_length]
        
        return wave, sample_rate
    async def process_augmentation(self, wave, sr, file, dir_name):
        """
        Perform all augmentations on a single file sequentially with memory cleanup.
        """
        try:
            name = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]
            # Perform and save time stretch
            if self.needed_augs:
                await self.safe_process(
                    wave,
                    sr,
                    dir_name,
                    f"{name}_time",
                    lambda w, s: self.time_stretch(w, random.uniform(*self.audio_stretch_range)),
                )
                self.needed_augs -=1
                await asyncio.sleep(self.saving_break)
            if self.needed_augs:
                # Perform and save pitch shift
                await self.safe_process(
                    wave,
                    sr,
                    dir_name,
                    f"{name}_pitch",
                    lambda w, s: self.pitch_shift(w, s, random.uniform(*self.audio_pitch_range)),
                )
    
                self.needed_augs -=1
                await asyncio.sleep(self.saving_break)
            if self.needed_augs:
                # Perform and save noise addition
                await self.safe_process(
                    wave,
                    sr,
                    dir_name,
                    f"{name}_noise",
                    lambda w, s: self.add_noise(w, snr_db=random.uniform(*self.snr_range)),
                )
                self.needed_augs -=1
                await asyncio.sleep(self.saving_break)
            if self.needed_augs:
                # Perform and save reverb
                await self.safe_process(
                    wave,
                    sr,
                    dir_name,
                    f"{name}_reverb",
                    lambda w, s: self.apply_reverb(w, s, decay=random.uniform(*self.reverb_decay_range),
                                                delay_ms=random.randint(*self.reverb_delay_range)),
                )
                self.needed_augs -=1
                await asyncio.sleep(self.saving_break)

            logger.info(f"Completed all augmentations for {file}")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error during augmentations for {file}: {e}")

    async def safe_process(self, wave, sr, dir_name, name_suffix, augmentation_fn):
        """
        Safely process and save each augmentation step.
        """
        try:
            augmented_wave = augmentation_fn(wave, sr)
            await self.save_file(augmented_wave, sr, dir_name, name_suffix)
            del augmented_wave
            gc.collect()  # Force garbage collection after saving
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error in {name_suffix}: {e}")
    async def save_file(self, audio, sr, dir_name, name_suffix):
        """
        Save the processed audio to the appropriate folder.
        """
        try:
            output_dir = os.path.join(Data_set_Augmented_path, dir_name)
            os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
            output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"{name_suffix}_{int(time.perf_counter_ns())}.ogg")
    
            # Save the file asynchronously
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            await loop.run_in_executor(None, sf.write, output_path, audio, sr)
            while not os.path.isfile(output_path):
                logger.info("Waiting for file to save...")
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Adjust the delay as needed
    
            logger.info(f"Saved file: {output_path}")
            
            # Explicitly release memory
            del audio
            gc.collect()
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error saving file {name_suffix}: {e}")

    async def ssave_file(self, audio, sr, dir_name, name_suffix):
        """
        Save the processed audio to the appropriate folder.
        """
        try:
            output_dir = os.path.join(Data_set_Augmented_path, dir_name)
            os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
            output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"{name_suffix}_{int(time.perf_counter_ns())}.ogg")

            # Save the file asynchronously
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            await loop.run_in_executor(None, sf.write, output_path, audio, sr)
            while not os.path.isfile(output_path):
                print("waited 5 microseconds")
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
            logger.info(f"Saved file: {output_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error saving file {name_suffix}: {e}")

    def pitch_shift(self, audio, sr, n_steps):
        """Apply pitch shift."""
        return librosa.effects.pitch_shift(audio, sr=sr, n_steps=n_steps)

    def time_stretch(self, audio, rate):
        """Apply time stretch."""
        return librosa.effects.time_stretch(audio, rate=rate)

    def add_noise(self, audio, snr_db=20):
        """Add noise dynamically."""
        signal_power = np.mean(audio ** 2)
        snr_linear = 10 ** (snr_db / 10)
        noise_power = signal_power / snr_linear
        noise = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(noise_power), audio.shape)
        return audio + noise

    def apply_reverb(self, audio, sr, decay=0.5, delay_ms=50):
        """Simulate reverb."""
        delay_samples = int(sr * (delay_ms / 1000.0))
        impulse_response = np.zeros(delay_samples * 4)
        impulse_response[::delay_samples] = decay ** np.arange(4)
        reverb_audio = fftconvolve(audio, impulse_response, mode='full')
        return reverb_audio[:len(audio)]


    def calculate_augs_loop(self, len):
        m = self.datasetbalance - len
        return m, int(math.ceil(m/self.augmentation_variations))
    # Function to apply pitch shifting

# Example usage
def load_data(data_path):
    """Load dataset structure."""
    results = []
    for speaker_dir in os.listdir(data_path):
        speaker_path = os.path.join(data_path, speaker_dir)
        if os.path.isdir(speaker_path):
            files = [(os.path.join(speaker_path, f), speaker_dir) for f in os.listdir(speaker_path)]
            results.append(files)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Data_set_files = load_data("D:/Projects/Dataset/CustomDatasets/DataSet_001_Augmented")
    Data_set_Augmented_path = "D:/Projects/Dataset/CustomDatasets/DataSet_001_Augmented"
    dataset_augment = DatasetAugmentation(Data_set_files)

    # Create an event loop if not already running
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(dataset_augment.augment_dataset())

when i run this code it is showing a message and exiting the program now exception the messages says the kernel died and will be restarted automatically

That is over 200 lines of code that no one here has ever seen before. You need to reduce it to a [mre], or explain exactly where the overflow occurs.

If you're getting a stack overflow, there must be recursion, not a loop.

show the all the errors thrown please (copy/paste the resulting trace produced by)
